# Correct way to suspend coroutine until Task<T> is complete

Tags: android, kotlin, task, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I've recently dove into Kotlin coroutines
Since I use a lot of Google's libraries, most of the jobs is done inside [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) class

Currently I'm using this extension to suspend coroutine

```
suspend fun <T> awaitTask(task: Task<T>): T = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    task.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            continuation.resume(task.result)
        } else {
            continuation.resumeWithException(task.exception!!)
        }
    }
}
```

But recently I've seen usage like this

```
suspend fun <T> awaitTask(task: Task<T>): T = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    try {
        val result = Tasks.await(task)
        continuation.resume(result)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        continuation.resumeWithException(e)
    }
}
```

Is there any difference, and which one is correct?

UPD: second example isn't working, idk why

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The block of code passed to `suspendCoroutine { ... }` should not block a thread that it is being invoked on, allowing the coroutine to be suspended. This way, the actual thread can be used for other tasks. This is a key feature that allows Kotlin coroutines to scale and to run multiple coroutines even on the single UI thread.

The first example does it correctly, because it invokes [`task.addOnCompleteListener` (see docs)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<TResult>)) (which just adds a listener and returns immediately. That is why the first one works properly.

The second example uses [`Tasks.await(task)` (see docs)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#await(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<TResult>)) which *blocks* the thread that it is being invoked on and does not return until the task is complete, so it does not allow coroutine to be properly suspended.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to wait for a [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) to complete using **Kotlin Coroutines** is to convert the `Task` object into a [`Deferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/) object by applying [`Task.asDeferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/as-deferred.html) extension function. For example for fetching data from **Firebase Database** it can look like the following:

```
suspend fun makeRequest() {
    val task: Task<DataSnapshot> = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.get()
    val deferred: Deferred<DataSnapshot> = task.asDeferred()
    val data: Iterable<DataSnapshot> = deferred.await().children

    // ... use data
}
```

Dependency for `Task.asDeferred()`:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.5.2'
```

To call `suspend` function we need to launch a coroutine:

```
someCoroutineScope.launch {
    makeRequest()
}
```

`someCoroutineScope` is a [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/) instance. In android it can be [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) in [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) class and [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) in `Activity` or `Fragment`, or some custom `CoroutineScope` instance. Dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
```